# Android rgb color api

Tags: android, api

http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html

in the left side of above url

1. one box is there which displays color and below to that R G B input fields are there
   on filling a value and clicking Set RGB ,we  can see the new color

is there any api for doing the same in Andorid

Comment: Are you looking for a UI control or a utility class for calculating color values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)) class which is an default android class.

```
int rgb = Color.rgb(red, blue, green)
```

it has static method `rgb()` which takes the red, blue and green colors and returns the mixed color.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this small snip it:

```
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8)  & 0xFF;
int b =  color        & 0xFF;
```

This takes your color and converts it to the *channels*. The `>>` operator does bit shifting which is equal to a division of 256 or 65536. That is by the way the same thing what the `android.graphics.Color` class does internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [android.graphics.Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class.
It has a `red(int)`, `green(int)` and `blue(int)` method (among some others useful methods).